# Physics of the capacitance of an electrolytic capacitor

Tags: capacitance, electrical-engineering, dielectric, applied-physics

In explanations about the electrolytic capacitor one often cites the formula

$$
C = \epsilon_r \epsilon_0 \frac{A}{d}
$$

for the capacitance $C$. Then one says that by enlarging the area $A$ via etching, the capacity will increase.

[image]

However the formula above is for parallel plates and not for irregular surfaces. Furthermore applying this formula partwise by making the surface rough, you get places where the distance is larger so making the capacity locally smaller.

So how to make the the usual textbook argument more exact:

- Since the surface is irregular, it doesn't seem to have a closed formula for the capacitance. However how to more rigerously, for example starting from the laplace equation that making the surface rough increases the capacitance.
- How can one estimate of how much the surface is enlarged by etching?
- How do in a real electrolytic capacitor the depths of the "embayments" compare to the thickness of the electrolyte layer?

Comment: One can't "extract" this from first principles and for the people who make electrolytic capacitors that's of no concern, to begin with. They develop methods of etching that produce useful capacitors, no matter what formula could be used for estimating the capacitance. If you want, you can plug an effective area and an effective thickness into the formula, but that's an ad-hoc approximation. The actual impedance of these capacitors is a lot more complicated than the simple formula suggests, which is why one should never use an electrolytic in a critical application.